# Write HTML ul li element to Excel using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am exporting excel file from the database using PHP. Data contain html tags which want to write in excel as display in browser i.e. bullets points.

I want the final excel generated like,

- Coffee
- Tea
- Milk

Please help me.

Comment: Sure! What have you tried? Please, post your code so far.

Comment: $terms_cond = stripslashes('<ul><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li>');
    $terms_cond = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $terms_cond);
    $objTermSheet->SetCellValue('A5', $terms_cond);
    $objTermSheet->setTitle("Terms & Conditions");